# What EAP type to use on Public Wifi 802.1X?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ieee802.1x, radius

I understand you cannot use EAP-TLS for public wifi because the clients will not have their own certificates, therefore what EAP do you use, so that mutual authentication can take place?

Comment: Please define *mutual* in the context of *public* Wi-Fi. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want clients to connect with passwords. You want to use either [PEAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) or [EAP-TTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP-TTLS) with [MSCHAPv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-CHAPv2) as the inner authentication method. You will probably still need to provide clients with a CA certificate to verify the server with.

Answer (score 0):

PEAP with MSCHAPv2 is the most compatible. Except Windows desktops, all other devices directly connect and prompt you for the username / password. You don't need a trusted server certificate; it can be self signed.

On Windows, you will need to manually create the connection and disable server certificate trust verification, or get a certificate from a trusted CA. This is not the same trust store as the browser and has a much more limited set of root CAs.